# Клиент для веб-службы ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, веб-служба

Пусть, например, приложение для произведения некоторых вычислений использует веб-службу. Для этой службы нужно написать клиент (на delphi,... хоть на чем), работающий локально на машине клиента. При некотом событии в приложении (работающем на броузере), оно дает службе команду передать или принять некую информацию с локального клиента. *Возможно ли это*?
*Возникает* другая задача, как идентифицировать локального клиента, это уже вопрос другой.
*Нужно* для доступа к файловой системе клиента.

Comment: Есть вариант применить службу `WCF`, с которой может взаимодействовать и ASP.NET и десктопное приложение. Что скажете? Можно ли файлы передавать?

Comment: На вирус похоже :). Обычно браузеры не разрешают Web-приложениям работать с файловой системой на клиенте.

Comment: Не вирус. Броузерам закрыт доступ к файловой системе, а нашему приложению нужно иметь.

Comment: Сделал WCF-службу.